# Remove White Border and vertical / Horizontal image in html table cell

Tags: css, html

From my searching both on the wider web and on here it seems this is a question asked many many times but for the last few weeks I have not been able to find a answer that does what I want.

I am using a third party (paid for) responsive template on blogger.com.

I am creating a new page (not a post) that needs to have a html table.

The first cell of each new row will contain an image which will always be the same size.

I would like this image to be centered both vertically and horizontally, and I need the white border around the image removed.

I know basic html and some CSS but with blogger templates the css tends to be within the html (from what i can tell).

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">.nobrtable br { display: none } tr {text-align: center;} tr.alt td  {background-color: #eeeecc; color: black;} tr {text-align: center;} caption {caption-side:bottom;}    </style>

<br />
<table border="2" bordercolor="#0033FF" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:  #99ffff; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;"><tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #0033ff; color: white; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-top: 5px;">
<th width="15%"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Column 1</span></th> <!-- COLUMN NAME 1 -->
<th width="20%"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Column 2</span></th> <!-- COLUMN NAME 2 -->
<th width="20%"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Column 3</span></th> <!-- COLUMN NAME 3 -->
<th width="20%"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Column 4</span></th> <!-- COLUMN NAME 4 -->
<th width="25%"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Column 5</span></th> <!-- COLUMN NAME 5 -->
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<img border="0" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" /></div>
<br /></td>
<td>Table Cell A2</td>
<td>Table Cell A3</td>
<td>Table Cell A4</td>
<td>Table Cell A5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell B1</td>
<td>Table Cell B2</td>
<td>Table Cell B3</td>
<td>Table Cell B4</td>
<td>Table Cell B5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td>Table Cell C1</td>
<td>Table Cell C2</td>
<td>Table Cell C3</td>
<td>Table Cell C4</td>
<td>Table Cell C5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell D1</td>
<td>Table Cell D2</td>
<td>Table Cell D3</td>
<td>Table Cell D4</td>
<td>Table Cell D5</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

As a footnote to help anyone else who encounters my problem I have solved it by doing the following.

add this to the main blog css to get rid of the white border:

```
.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img,
.BlogList .item-thumbnail img {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```

and then use this to center the image:

```
<td align="center" valign="center"><img src="*image url*;" /></td>
```

hope this is of help to others

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting the cellpadding attribute to zero.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `<img>` tags and really anything from those first cells. Then, in your stylesheet:

```
tr td:first-child {
    padding: 0px;
    background: url("http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg") no-repeat center;
}
```

If each cell's image should be different, you'll have to specify the background property for each of them seperately.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. I dont have access to the style sheet as its a third party template and the style is all set inline.

Comment: I discovered how to add inline styles and this worked to a point. There must be a better way than having to add this line of code for each image as there will eventually be a unknown number of images as the table is a list of products.....

Comment: forgive my ignorance of coding but can we not have a div that sets the image property's ?

Comment: Sure you can, I just didn't see the point. With this approach you can use — for every table — an image for the first row, for the second row, …

Comment: but for each image do i have to add your code again but changing the url for each image, for example, 30 images would need your code entering 30 times (each time with the unique url to the different images)?

Comment: If you want 30 different images, then yes. But you need to enter those 30 different images somewhere anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Find the updated [JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/a7t50upj/1/).

I am not able reproduce white border issue.

For making center align both vertically and horizontally.

```
td{ text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is, as I said in my original post that I do not have access to the CSS style sheets so for a single page it has to be an internal style sheet I guess

Comment: i worked out how to add inline style but your suggestion did not work plus for some reason I am still getting the white border around the picture

Comment: Are you developing email template? some times client system will ignore styles if you didn't specify properly

Comment: No. Its a html page for my blog at blogger.com